# Cleaning a computer CPU - Do gauze pads with polyester in them cause ESD?

Tags: cpu, esd, antistatic, static, cleaning

Do gauze pads, the type used for scrapes or burns, cause ESD if they have a mix of polyester in them?

What if the polyester mix gauze pads have rubbing alcohol on them too?

They don't have any lint that comes off of them, thus making them seem like they'd work for computer electronics cleaning.  (I'm currently looking for a way to get thermal paste off of a cpu.)

Thank you.

Comment: Why not a shop paper towel?

Comment: Do they cause any sort of static when used?  Thank you.

Comment: As with other paper towels shop towels are made of cellulose, and cellulose is antistatic when humid.

Comment: shop towels have too much lint for this purpose.

Comment: If it doesn't say ESD safe on the box then its probably not. If you want the guarantee that its ESD safe, then make sure it's marketed that way.

Comment: I use metallic wire dish scrubber. Also, not to remove the CPU unnecessarily, I use it with a vacuum cleaner when wiping the CPU.

Comment: A small pad, handled by a grounded person, (1) doesn't have enough electrical capacity to carry a harmful charge, (2) is discharging to the holder, and to all the non-sensitive electrical contacts it touches.

Comment: @Ayhan careful with the vacuum cleaner. The airflow through the plastic hose and the air flowing over the PCB can generate quite a bit of static electricity.

Comment: OK, thank you @NilsPipenbrinck, then I think it is better to earth the wire scrubber :)

Answer (score 1):

> Valutek’s ESD polyester wiper is constructed from 100% continuous-filament polyester in a double-knit, no-run, interlock pattern with a conductive fiber designed to dissipate electrical charge.

But if wipe is not the same as above but your paste has silver in it, then ok.

You can use a razor blade then wipe carefully.  Lint free is good.

Comment: I remember cleaning a "smoker's" faulty motherboard from dirt with a toothbrush and IsoPropAlcohal. The leads on every chip were dust so thick it looked like felt between the leads. It worked after forced air drying.  The dust contaminates the insulation of the IPA dielectric to become a good antistat.

Answer (score 1):

I Use [Kim wipes](https://www.google.com/search?q=Kim%20wipes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=Kim%20wipes&tbm=shop) or [ESD swabs](https://www.google.com/search?q=Kim+wipes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#tbm=shop&q=esd+swabs) in conjunction with [Tech Spray flux remover](https://www.google.com/search?q=Kim%20wipes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#tbm=shop&q=tech%20spray%20flux%20remover) to remove flux or thermal paste. If you have to you can then use some kind of lint free swab or wipe and spray a little flux spray on it to remove the last of the residue.

Here is the best method however, If you get the CPU cold the thermal paste will solidify and wipe right off. This works especially well with the evil white paste that gets onto everything, as soon as that stuff gets cold you can wipe a surface clean.

If its just a consumer CPU (thats pretty much disposable) then just use whatever comes in handy to wipe the thermal paste off.